# How to properly implement concrete class that inherits interface with List<AnotherInterface>

Tags: c#

I have a proposed dictionary item schema that looks like this:

```
public interface IDataDictionary
{
    List<IDataDictionaryItem> DictionaryItems { get; set; }
}
```

And the dictionary items as:

```
public interface IDataDictionaryItem
{
    Guid Guild { get; set; }

    int SequenceId { get; set; }

    string Title { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    string Language { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to implement this in a concrete class like such:

```
public class HairColorDictionary : IDataDictionary
{
    public List<HairColor> DictionaryItems { get; set; }
}
```

With the items concrete implementation:

```
public class HairColor : IDataDictionaryItem
{
    public Guid Guild { get; set; }
    public int SequenceId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I get the error message below, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.
Can someone please enlighten me where this went wrong.

Error message:

> Error CS0738 'HairColorDictionary' does not implement interface member 'IDataDictionary.DictionaryItems'. 'HairColorDictionary.DictionaryItems' cannot implement 'IDataDictionary.DictionaryItems' because it does not have the matching return type of 'List'.

Comment: There is a certain similarity to the referenced possible duplicate, but this certanly provided a better understanding of the problem/solution from a different point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you're trying to get at and the reason it doesn't work is because the interface defined a collection that is non specific (that interface could be implemented), but you're trying to implement that interface member in a specific way.

If you really must do this you can do it with generics. Here's the updated bits:

```
public interface IDataDictionary<T> where T : IDataDictionaryItem
{
    List<T> DictionaryItems { get; set; }
}

public class HairColorDictionary : IDataDictionary<HairColor>
{
    public List<HairColor> DictionaryItems { get; set; }
}
```

`T` allows you to use anything and the `where T:...` part puts a constraint on it.

Please realize that is a potential answer to your solution. I've not taken the time to ponder the upsides or downsides of it.

Comment: That actually solved my problem, and also provided a better understanding of the workings of interface inheritance. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation, `HairColorDictionary` `is-a` `IDataDictionary`. So i could do something bad like:

```
IDataDictionary d = new HairColorDictionary();
d.DictionaryItems.add(blah);
```

Here add method expects something of type `IDataDictionaryItem` and not necessarily `HairColor` because `d` is just `IDataDictionary` and not `HairColorDictionary`! So i could do something like

```
class SkinColor : IDataDictionaryItem { ... }
IDataDictionaryItem s = new SkinColor();
d.DictionaryItems.add(s);
```

Question is whether this last statement is valid or not? It should be valid because `add` expects a `IDataDictionaryItem` which `SkinColor` correctly implements. But then it should not be valid because the actual `public List<HairColor> DictionaryItems` only allows `HairColor`s and not `SkinColor`s!!!

To eliminate all this confusion and to maintain strict type safety, you have to follow Covarience and Contravarience rules. Or you can go ahead with @TheMuffinMan's nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689649/1043824).

Comment: Yes, agreed. Before asking the question I was not realizing that possibility. Due to lack of understanding of course. I learned a valuable lesson with this. And thank you for also sheding some lite to it as well!